# Macro averaged in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am performing a binary classification and I compute macro averaged manually for example like the following:

```
macro_averaged= (FPR+FNR)*float(0.5)
```

where FPR and FNR are computed as follows:

```
FPR= FP/float(FP+TN)
FNR= FN/float(FN+TP)
```

and I am getting (0.184484722594
) however, I am getting different result .. which is (0.885836909871) when I use the scikit-learn function :

```
print f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='binary')
```

Shouldn't they be the same in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calclute precision and recall for each class using the following formula:

```
Precison = tp / (fp + tp)
Recall = tp / (tp + fn)
```

Then take their macro average as:

```
AveragePrecision = (Precison_classA + Precission_classB)/ 2
AverageRecall = (Recall_classA + Recall_classB)/ 2
```

Then finally use the formula for F1 as:

```
F1 = 2 * (AveragePrecision * AverageRecall) / (AveragePrecision + AverageRecall)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [formula](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) for the F1 score is

```
F1 = 2 * (pr * re) / (pr + re)
```

with precision `pr = tp / (fp + tp)` and recall `re = tp / (tp + fn)`

What you compute as `macro_averaged` is something entirely different.

Comment: what I want to calculate is the macro averaged does it has the same formula as F1 that you have provide in your answer ? because the names are very confusing!

Comment: The term "macro average" describes how to combine true positives, false positives, etc. from several measurements. In macro average you first compute the scores and average them. In micro average you combine all TPs, FPs, etc. and compute the measure from the combination. Neither is related to what you seem to be doing.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the F1 score (using type 1, type 2 errors) is

[image: F1 score equation]

While you compute

[image]

(Note that TN does not even appear in the equation for the f1 score)

Comment: can you tell me please what does the second formula compute ?

Comment: @user2739381 ah, that's just your formula for `macro_averaged= (FPR+FNR)*float(0.5)` with FPR and FNR plugged in ;-)   I think the answer given by Riyaz is what you were looking for.